# Unity XR Interaction Toolkit How to realize grasp the steering wheel and control the rotation of the steering wheel When I developing a vr project?

Tags: c#

I try to use XRGrabInteractable to control the rotation,but the handle controls the object's x,y, and z axes at the same time, and I couldn't find a way to control the steering wheel's y axis separately.

Is there a way to let the hands control the steering wheel, just like you normally drive?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.